# Há algo de errado em formular uma pergunta só para trazer conteudo de outra comunidade?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, responder-a-si-mesmo

Formulei a seguinte pergunta

> [Como obter resultados randômicos em SQL com diferentes SGDBs?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/294295/3635)

Até hoje, com 7 anos de participação no site fiz apenas 5 perguntas no estilo, então não é nem de longe um abuso, se eu tivesse feito 10 perguntas meia-boca por dia até entenderia, mas não é o caso, são 5 perguntas em 7 anos.

Meu objetivo é trazer algum conteúdo que pensei ser útil a comunidade, "centralizado", para facilitar.

Seguindo o que é dito no Help: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

> Sim! O Stack Exchange [**sempre incentivou explicitamente**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) os usuários a responder suas próprias perguntas. Se você tem uma pergunta da qual já sabe a resposta e gostaria de documentar esse conhecimento em público para que outros (inclusive você mesmo) possam encontrá-lo posteriormente, é perfeitamente normal fazer e responder sua própria pergunta em um site do Stack Exchange.

Entendo que é permitido e que é saudável, agora me pergunto existe algum motivo para isto ser visto como um problema para a comunidade? Ou simplesmente a pergunta tem problemas (assim como a resposta)?

Eu sinceramente fico muito desmotivado, as pessoas parecem pensar que é oportunismo.

A dúvida é, existe algum motivo para os downvotes na pergunta e resposta e é ou não algo relacionado ao conteúdo da postagem ou é um problema com discordar do [self-answer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)?

Comment: A pergunta, como está formulada, tem mais metaconteúdo do que conteúdo. Pode ser o motivo dos downvotes. Eu cortaria todos os seus *disclaimers*.

Comment: @bfavaretto se for isso supostamente, então acho que as pessoas especificas desvalorizam a sinceridade, eu afirmei que não era uma pergunta original, mas sim para buscar compartilhar algo, apontei as origens, acredito que fiz o certo, que foi ser sincero em todos pontos e de onde obtive o conteudo, citando fontes, tem gente que não faz nem isso, ter várias respostas por ai que não creditam ninguém, inclusive ontem vi uma com código que eu fiz. Eu entendo que não dá para agradar a todos, mas parece que as pessoas só enxergam duas coisas no SO, assistencialismo/suporte técnico e gamefication.

Comment: Para mim foi bem útil o post. E já adicionei aos favoritos ;)

Comment: Claro que é bem-vindo responder sua própria pergunta se você descobriu a resposta. Mas como fez, você criou uma pergunta que já existia e você mesmo respondeu com uma resposta que já existia. Imagine se todos, principalmente os bem ativos no site (como você), começassem a fazer isto? Não me parece algo "natural" para o site. PS: Eu não dei negativo.

Comment: @Dherik não parecer natural demonstra então que as pessoas desconhecem o funcionamento da ferramente que é descrita no Helpo: > Para incentivar as pessoas a fazer isso, há uma caixa de seleção na parte inferior da página cada vez que você faz uma pergunta. Se você tiver mais de 15 pontos de reputação e já sabe a resposta, clique na caixa de seleção "Responder sua própria pergunta" na parte inferior da página Fazer uma pergunta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, eu não me fiz claro. Digo "não parecer natural" não no sentido de responder a própria pergunta, mas fazer nas condições que fez: a pergunta já existia e já estava respondida no SOen. Aproveitando, responder a própria pergunta me é justificável em duas ocasiões: 1) eu perguntei, ninguém me respondeu e achei a resposta sozinho. 2) eu tinha uma dúvida que não achei no SO, encontrei a resposta sozinho, e agora desejo criar a pergunta e já respondê-la.

Comment: @Dherik para algo parecer natural tem que existir o entendimento intermediário da ferramenta, se o entendimento minimo é o que a pessoal possui então sim, vai parecer que é anti-natural algo que deveria ser natural. Uma coisa é não parecer natural porque as pessoas simplesmente só conhecem o minimo, outra coisa é ser algo incomum (o que eu fiz é incomum apenas, ao menos para quem entende o básico e entende os diferentes propósitos do site).

Comment: Faca, mas faca com moderação. Nao poste perguntas só para o postar e tente evitar trazer várias perguntas num curto escapo de tempo. De também tempo para outras pessoas responderem antes de si. Como voce tem reputacao voce pode até icentivar os outros usuários a responder á sua pergunta oferecendo uma recompensa.  Se calhar até se vai surpreender com as respostas. Acho que assim ninguém se chateia :)

Comment: @BrunoCosta então o ideal seria remover a opção nativa da ferramenta, já que parece que o pessoal pensa mais no gamefication do que no conteudo :P ... ai o problema não é comigo ou com a pergunta e sim com a Stack Overflow :P

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Nao sei. Eu acho que a pergunta é a seguinte: Considera razoável trazer 20 perguntas num dia? Eu acho que é interessante pensar sobre isso. Eu considero que haja valor em trazer perguntas para cá mas nao acho que deve de haver um cacador de perguntas para as transferir explicitamente. Está a entender?

Comment: @BrunoCosta eu faço isso uma vez a cada 6 meses, é algo bem raro, até hoje, estou a 5 anos no site, só fiz 4 perguntas assim. O problema pra mim é outra coisa, são pessoas que não entendem a ferramenta e que pensam que isso se trata de oportunismo ou que isso não traz nada pra comunidade ou que sou algum tipo de egoista, e o motivo disto é o mesmo dos VOTOS mal usados, as pessoas olham o autor da postagem e não o conteudo na maioria das vezes.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Entao do meu ponto de vista parece estar tudo certo :). Sim, é pena alguns usuários nao perceberem qual é a utilidade disso. Por mais que nao seja muitas vez traz conteúdo interessante. Acho que normalmente quem traz perguntas para cá escolhe sempre as mais interessantes consoante o seu ponto de vista obviamente.

Comment: Eu sou vejo como válido, mas não espere muito reconhecimento por "ser sincero"... até onde eu sei, aqui sinceridade às vezes não tem muito valor (eu disse: às vezes).

Answer (score 9):

Como vc colocou a tag [debate] vou dar minha humilde opinião se não se importa.

Eu vejo sim com bons olhos. Pois também vejo o site como um imenso banco de dados e não só como q&a. Principalmente no que se refere a perguntas mais antigas que já foram revisadas e complementadas com outras respostas etc.

Eu mesmo as vezes me deparo com coisas que eu gostaria de compartilhar, pois acredito que a comunidade seria beneficiada com isso. Mas quando vc se responde logo em seguida as pessoas podem se sentir desmotivadas em responder também, pois podem acreditar que será um esforço não recompensado.

Ao meu ver, mesmo vc já tendo a resposta na manga seria interessante deixar que as pessoas se sintam motivadas a responder, principalmente pq boa parte dos usuários são motivados pelos pontos infelizmente. Sendo assim, vc deveria talvez esperar algum tempo antes de se auto-responder...

Por outro lado, se vc pensar a longo prazo e a qualidade da pergunta e da resposta forem boas com certeza essa placar vai se reverter!

Comment: Se sente desmotivado que entende que o sistema é para só ganhar pontos, minha intenção não são os pontos, é compartilhar conteudo que eu acredito ser util, e até aonde entendo isso é incentivado. Gamefication é uma ferramenta para atrair a maioria, mas não é obrigatoriedade e nem o principal foco.

Comment: Sim @GuilhermeNascimento esse é o lado negro da gamificação, as pessoas querem os pontos, e uma pergunta que já foi respondida pelo próprio autor pode se tornar desinteressante. Sei que isso não explica os DownVotes, mas muitos usuários não entendem como funciona a plataforma e acabam agindo assim. Talvez seja interessante também colocar alguma observação quanto a isso quando for se alto-responder se achar necessário.

Answer (score 2):

Não há problema algum e não pode ser considerado oportunismo, segundo até mesmo a [documentação mencionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Agora, o fato de receber *downs* esbarra na questão de que o usuário pode votar como quiser -- sendo o voto bom ou ruim, aí já são outros quinhentos.

Pelo que entendo, o SOpt, além de ser um site de perguntas e respostas, tem por objetivo ser um repositório de conhecimento e pesquisa, logo é super válido trazer informações onde usuários possam encontrar informações para sanar suas dúvidas. Logo, não há problema algum em perguntar e responder à sua própria pergunta, compartilhando à comunidade conhecimento.

Concordo com o que disse o [@hugocsl](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/97477/hugocsl):

> Ao meu ver, mesmo vc já tendo a resposta na manga seria interessante
>   deixar que as pessoas se sintam motivadas a responder[...]

Acho interessante ver as respostas dos usuários, e quem sabe, seja igual ou melhor do que você já tinha em mente. Assim motivando e recompensando outros usuários que postaram boas respostas.

Mas no geral, não vejo oportunismo ou qualquer forma desonesta nesta prática. Não apenas acho válido como até recomendado. A intenção de compartilhar e agregar informações ao site, neste caso, ao meu ver, está em primeiro plano. Receber *downs* ou *ups*, acho que pode ser relevado se a intenção foi boa.

Quem vota *down* nesses casos, provavelmente ainda não entendeu o propósito do site, principalmente se não deixou um comentário justificando seu voto.